# How to Customize the currency symbol accordingly with the language-country code?

Tags: javascript, angular

As I'm looking forward to a currency symbol based on the language-country code as input. But, when I give input for the country "Saudi Arabia" I'll get a result which I'm not expected where I'm expecting only the Saudi currency symbol but not everything in the Arabic language. So, if anyone knows how to customize the currency symbol using the same code as mentioned below. Please help me with this. I've mentioned code and result in the below code and images.[image]

```
let formated = (new Intl.NumberFormat('ar-SA', { style: 'currency', currency: 'SAR' }).format(value));
```

I've expected currency symbol then normal English digits instead of Arabic digits.

(ر.س.‏ --> this is the currency symbol for Saudi Arabia & ٦٠٠٫٠٠ --> this is number which is needed to be shown in normal English digits. Please help to show it in --->  ر.س.‏ 0.00 using above-mentioned code)

Comment: Would `let formated = value + (new Intl.NumberFormat(ar-SA, { style: 'currency', currency: SAR }).format(''));` work ?

Comment: @Gilsido I've tried this but, I'm getting following result ٠٫٠٠ ر.س.‏3000 but I'm expecting ر.س.‏3000. And I don't want that digits to be shown again in Arabic.

Comment: Seems to work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-48cmkh. Is it working with en-US USD?

Comment: @youri  en-US USD is working fine but not with ar-SA SAR!!!

Comment: @GurudathG please see my updated answer. It is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
let formated = (new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'SAR' }).format(value));
```

Comment: if i use the above code. i'm getting following result (SAR 3,000.00). But, i need result in 3000 ر.س.

Comment: [international numeric conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) shows that you want to use a different locale style, german for example. I've updated the answer

Comment: but i want it for saudi arabia. could you please help me on the same?

Comment: @GurudathG if you just want to have a SAR currency symbol, I suggest you use [angular currency pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)

Comment: let a = String.fromCharCode(65020); // Currency symbol of Saudhi Arabia
let b = "123.42"; // string
let res = a + b; // expected result SAR currency symbol + 123.42 but its showing in inverted fashion. 123.42 +  SAR currency symbol. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions:

- with `formatCurrency` from `@angular/common`:

```js
import { formatCurrency } from '@angular/common';

[...]

let formated = formatCurrency(value, 'en-US', '\u0631\u002e\u0633\u002e');
```

- with the `CurrencyPipe`:

```js
<p>{{ value | currency:'SAR':'\u0631\u002e\u0633\u002e'}}</p>
```

The 2 solutions will display:

> ر.س.10.00

(I'm not sure about the unicode but it seems to be correct)

Comment: what if the currency is dynamically changing based on locale?

Comment: I've checked with the above Unicode its not displaying with the expected result. I'm getting SAR 10.00 as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the formatter to use **latin numbering system** by adding `u-nu-latn` after the locale.

This will display the currency code in Arabic but the numbers in Latin.

Here it is:

```js
let value = 123.45

let formated = (new Intl.NumberFormat('ar-SA-u-nu-latn', { style: 'currency', currency: 'SAR' }).format(value));

console.log(formated);
```